# Chart Notes are Not Shown in Flexdashboard if an Empty Chunk is Added at the End

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

When adding a final chunk after the last chart chunk in a `flexdashboard` the notes (the text added below the chart via `> ...`) are silently dropped.

If you remove the final chunk (`clean-up-chunk`) the notes will re-appear.

This strikes me to be a bug, but before I issue a bug report, I am wondering whether this is maybe by design and we should not add empty (i.e. no graphical output producing) chunks at the end?

#### Code

````r
---
title: "Clean Up Chunk is Bad"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
---

```{r}
library(plotly)
```

## Row

### A Chart

```{r chart-chunk}
plot_ly(x = 1, y = 10, type = "bar")
```
> Text not shown if chunk `clean-up-chunk` is added at the end

```{r clean-up-chunk}
### Remove this chunk altogether to make the note re-appear again
### Usage: for example to close a db connection
## dbDisconnect(con)
```
````

#### Screenshot

[image: Rendered Flexdashboard with teh Note below the Chart missing]

Comment: If I add the option `include = FALSE` to the clean-up chunk, the text appears after the plot. But of course, the question remains why the text does not show otherwise. I have checked that the text is in the html-file even when it does not show up in the browser.